# Vega-lite: line mark not consistent in overview+ detailed responsive chart

Tags: javascript, charts, vega-lite, vega

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@5.22.1"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@5.2.0"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@6.20.8"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="vis"/>
  <script>
    const spec = {
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "name": "source_0",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"Items": "3", "Items_Rate": "0.20", "Month": "Jan-21"},
      {"Items": "6", "Items_Rate": "0.40", "Month": "Feb-21"},
      {"Items": "2", "Items_Rate": "0.20", "Month": "Mar-21"},
      {"Items": "4", "Items_Rate": "0.30", "Month": "Apr-21"},
      {"Items": "8", "Items_Rate": "0.45", "Month": "May-21"},
      {"Items": "9", "Items_Rate": "0.50", "Month": "Jun-21"},
      {"Items": "1", "Items_Rate": "0.10", "Month": "Jul-21"},
      {"Items": "5", "Items_Rate": "0.35", "Month": "Aug-21"},
      {"Items": "4", "Items_Rate": "0.28", "Month": "Sep-21"},
      {"Items": "7", "Items_Rate": "0.37", "Month": "Oct-21"},
      {"Items": "1", "Items_Rate": "0.50", "Month": "Nov-21"},
      {"Items": "4", "Items_Rate": "0.35", "Month": "Dec-21"}
    ]
  },
  "vconcat": [
    {
      "width": 850,
      "height": 250,
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": {"type": "bar", "size": 50, "tooltip": true},
          "transform": [{"filter": {"param": "brush"}}],
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "Month",
              "type": "ordinal",
              "sort": null,
              "scale": {"domain": {"param": "brush"}, "zero": true},
              "axis": {
                "title": "",
                "labelAngle": 360,
                "tickSize": 20,
                "position": 0
              }
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "Items",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": {"tickMinStep": 1}
            },
            "color": {
              "datum": "No. of Items",
              "scale": {"range": ["#0065ad"]}
            },
            "tooltip": [
              {"field": "Month", "type": "nominal", "title": "Month"},
              {
                "field": "Items",
                "type": "quantitative",
                "title": "No. of Items"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "line",
            "point": {"shape": "square", "size": "50"},
            "size": "2",
            "tooltip": true
          },
          "transform": [{"filter": {"param": "brush"}}],
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "Month",
              "type": "nominal",
              "title": "",
              "sort": null,
              "scale": {"domain": {"param": "brush"}}
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "Items_Rate",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "title": "Items",
              "scale": {"zero": false},
              "sort": null
            },
            "color": {
              "datum": "Items Rate",
              "scale": {"range": ["black"]},
              "legend": {"symbolType": "square"}
            },
            "tooltip": [
              {"field": "Month", "type": "nominal", "title": "Month"},
              {
                "field": "Items_Rate",
                "type": "quantitative",
                "title": "Rate"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "resolve": {
        "scale": {
          "y": "independent",
          "shape": "independent",
          "color": "independent",
          "size": "independent"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "width": "850",
      "height": 100,
      "mark": "bar",
      "params": [
        {
          "name": "brush",
          "select": {"type": "interval", "encodings": ["x"], "translate": true}
        }
      ],
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "Month",
          "type": "nominal",
          "sort": null,
          "axis": {"title": "", "labels": false, "ticks": false}
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "Items",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {
            "tickCount": 3,
            "grid": false,
            "title": "",
            "labels": false,
            "ticks": false
          }
        },
        "color": {"value": "#0065ad"}
      }
    }
  ],
  "config": {
    "axisY": {"minExtent": 40},
    "legend": {
      "orient": "top",
      "layout": {"top": {"anchor": "middle"}},
      "labelFont": "arial",
      "titleFont": "arial"
    }
  }
};
    vegaEmbed("#vis", spec, {mode: "vega-lite"}).then(console.log).catch(console.warn);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It can also be viewed in Vega lite editor here:
https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/da859f07e288d51da47a309ef2718ab2/responsive_chart.json

My query is that when I select 4 or more graphs and scroll forwards, everything is working properly. However when I scroll the same backwards, the line graphs becomes incorrect.
Instead of the nearest point creating a line to join the newly visible point, the farthest or the second-last visible graph now is joining the points.

How could I change the code to have only the nearest point join with the new point and not the order of how they became visible?

For example, in the screenshot below, the Sept-21 point should join the Aug-21 point and NOT Nov-21 when I take the scroll backwards.

[image]
Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a sort field. I added an index and used that but you can use anything you like.

[Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQspAjhoQMhgCcocAPoAGRSAAmSTClShiSQQzgQ0AbVABJTIifoAzCY9e+gBKFurohpQATMZKALJy9BoAUkiy-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-rduUaQVNpNYCpUIOVsHdZg4UgHB2gLf+gP1dKoy7WFmFmDhSB4Y917eS996PspICqRFdWaQKjSgxorWdO1JkbUZsMhZoGMXpR1GoLudgQHRaHwYhyGCM5i5uRFHleZTXh+YKoUYReUVkDFL1tqJIC5kobHKzkF4QFCCBMIuAAqxXoBAa3qCT86LsdOV5SBhUgBNJVlTBlUw9VYq1cj0uxtTztmyAdNGR1XXOz16CCkNz5KOtMiCKZi3sxFZMgF+uQjiMnQTjAy2AhnupvrkOdKC54vpyMWclwhaFbeghfV2+CFPvsFZVniNZtPWjYLQyQndusY0veO0n494N0qGot5ExOgFpojgcrfNHa2FDn3vmw0FkBPIAFB926yBAbYXKddGxxv33fr+am+8DiQ0+g4OQ-DC1IShSjmcxEeexoHFIFxQQ3gz7dVEt4HmQDz4qVvg7dArMXYtQMvTYynUNpf0sjQUSABhNghIFo+CUGQbQlY0AQL5tDWG-9AHgN5nAUBvYaGQJJuXB6Ng7AOA0AlJKKVgKtw+oWWQJ5fqgC-gATQvBDWQABRPIngc7vCUlrcgxcLwHlyvI52bBVxa2hLgxe84HIiPfDACuENTCmD4iTTigFugJA0OsGgFUKFwFsRohxFVW5AA)

```
   {
      "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
      "name": "source_0",
      "data": {
        "values": [
          {"Items": "3", "Items_Rate": "0.20", "Month": "Jan-21", "Index":1},
          {"Items": "6", "Items_Rate": "0.40", "Month": "Feb-21", "Index":2},
          {"Items": "2", "Items_Rate": "0.20", "Month": "Mar-21", "Index":3},
          {"Items": "4", "Items_Rate": "0.30", "Month": "Apr-21", "Index":4},
          {"Items": "8", "Items_Rate": "0.45", "Month": "May-21", "Index":5},
          {"Items": "9", "Items_Rate": "0.50", "Month": "Jun-21", "Index":6},
          {"Items": "1", "Items_Rate": "0.10", "Month": "Jul-21", "Index":7},
          {"Items": "5", "Items_Rate": "0.35", "Month": "Aug-21", "Index":8},
          {"Items": "4", "Items_Rate": "0.28", "Month": "Sep-21", "Index":9},
          {"Items": "7", "Items_Rate": "0.37", "Month": "Oct-21", "Index":10},
          {"Items": "1", "Items_Rate": "0.50", "Month": "Nov-21", "Index":11},
          {"Items": "4", "Items_Rate": "0.35", "Month": "Dec-21", "Index":12}
        ]
      },
    
      "vconcat": [
        {
          "width": 850,
          "height": 250,
          "layer": [
            {
              "mark": {"type": "bar", "size": 50, "tooltip": true},
              "transform": [{"filter": {"param": "brush"}}],
              "encoding": {
                "x": {
                  "field": "Month",
                  "type": "ordinal",
                  "sort": null,
                  "scale": {"domain": {"param": "brush"}, "zero": true},
                  "axis": {
                    "title": "",
                    "labelAngle": 360,
                    "tickSize": 20,
                    "position": 0
                  }
                },
                "y": {
                  "field": "Items",
                  "type": "quantitative",
                  "axis": {"tickMinStep": 1}
                },
                "color": {"datum": "No. of Items", "scale": {"range": ["#0065ad"]}},
                "tooltip": [
                  {"field": "Month", "type": "nominal", "title": "Month"},
                  {
                    "field": "Items",
                    "type": "quantitative",
                    "title": "No. of Items"
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "mark": {
                "type": "line",
                "point": {"shape": "square", "size": "50"},
                "size": "2",
                "tooltip": true
              },
              "transform": [{"filter": {"param": "brush"}}],
              "encoding": {
                "x": {
                  "field": "Month",
                  "type": "nominal",
                  "title": "",
                  "sort": {"field": "Index"},
                  "scale": {"domain": {"param": "brush"}}
                },
                "y": {
                  "field": "Items_Rate",
                  "type": "quantitative",
                  "title": "Items",
                  "scale": {"zero": false},
                  "sort": null
                },
                "color": {
                  "datum": "Items Rate",
                  "scale": {"range": ["black"]},
                  "legend": {"symbolType": "square"}
                },
                "tooltip": [
                  {"field": "Month", "type": "nominal", "title": "Month"},
                  {"field": "Items_Rate", "type": "quantitative", "title": "Rate"}
                ]
              }
            }
          ],
          "resolve": {
            "scale": {
              "y": "independent",
              "shape": "independent",
              "color": "independent",
              "size": "independent"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "width": "850",
          "height": 100,
          "mark": "bar",
          "params": [
            {
              "name": "brush",
              "select": {"type": "interval", "encodings": ["x"], "translate": true}
            }
          ],
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "Month",
              "type": "nominal",
              "sort": null,
              "axis": {"title": "", "labels": true, "ticks": false}
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "Items",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": {
                "tickCount": 3,
                "grid": false,
                "title": "",
                "labels": false,
                "ticks": false
              }
            },
            "color": {"value": "#0065ad"}
          }
        }
      ],
      "config": {
        "axisY": {"minExtent": 40},
        "legend": {
          "orient": "top",
          "layout": {"top": {"anchor": "middle"}},
          "labelFont": "arial",
          "titleFont": "arial"
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for figuring out the issue! If I wanted to use the months written in the specific order for sort, could you help in that? I did not want to mess with the input I had received, if possible. Meaning, I wanted to used the 'Month' column only.

Comment: It needs to be parsed into a proper date. At the moment, it isn't a date so you would need to write something to parse it. Don't forget to mark as solved if your question has been answered.

Comment: Another option is to provide the full sort array e.g.   "sort": ["Jan-21", "Feb-21","Mar-21", etc].